# Run Query for External List

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-designer

I have successfully created an external content type to my SharePoint and I have made a list from it.  The problem is my table has over 24000 records in it.  I need to grab the last 2000 records and not the first 2000 records as it seems to be doing.  Is there any way to run a query against the data I am getting to bring in the last 2000 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a Stored Procedure that brings the desired Last 2000 items for you, and create Read List Operation from Stored Procedure and rest from the table?

Stored Procedure can look like:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 columns FROM table
ORDER BY id_column
```

I hope this will work!

Comment: Ill give it a shot.  I am sure that is what I need to do.  I am just new at this :) I have never had to deal with anything SQL related with SharePoint until 2010.  It is good to learn new things.

Comment: Yeah please try that, and yes it always good to learn new things ;)

Comment: I cannot seem to get SPD to find my Stored Procedure.  I have went through the tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/10/173-a-step-by-step-guide-in-designing-bcs-entities-by-using-a-sql-stored-procedure.aspx"> here and I have been unable to get it to show up in my routines.  I love how frustrating SharePoint canbe sometimes.

Comment: Fixed it!  My problem was the way I was accessing the database.  I think my default permissions where not allowing me to see the stored procedures I created.  NOOB mistakes all around today :)

Comment: you are learning, so no problem :)

Comment: Worked like a charm once I figured out how to make the Secure Store Service and everything else to connect to the database properly.  I love the hoops SharePoint puts you through to get things done :)